# Exact Target Email API

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api

We are trying to use the Exact Target Email SOAP API with java and CXF.

When we make the request we are getting:-

> javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Fault string

and possibly fault code, not set.

There is no other error or exception stacktrace. Could you please let me know what could be the possible reason?